# Making an iOS and Android app that will only show a specified webpage and have the option to include forward/back buttons

Tags: android, html, ios, mobile, web

I need to make an app that will only display a public web url that mainly contains HTML, I want to be able to include back and forward buttons if a exact specific url is displayed or users can swipe from the side or something to display them (NO swiping from the side or bottom). I should be able to specify which domains and subdomains should be shown in the app and everything else would be opened in safari.

I would really appreciate if someone could find some kind of (free) solution or if they would like, they could make something for anyone else who is interested in having an Web Based App Template like this. Bonus points for Android and iOS versions and even more for iOS and iPad versions. Greatly Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be quite easy using UIWebView (on iOS)...
define your webview inside let's say the main UIViewController

```
UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView alloc]init];
webView.delegate = self
[webView loadHTMLString:@"yoursite.com" baseURL:nil]
```

on the delegate you should implement

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

  if(request.url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"any of the strings you want") {
     return YES;
  }

  else  {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.url]

     return NO;
  }


}
```

code is actually not tested but something by this idea should work on iOS...
i only can help you with the iOS part though... hope this helps you...

PS: to use the back and forward you should create a UIToolBar with two buttons and enable and disable them using

```
if(webView.canGoBack)
   backButton.enabled=YES;

if(webView.canGoForwad)
   forwardButton.enabled=YES;
```

and this buttons calls the method goBack and goForward of the UIWebView..

Comment: Thank You so much, I havent tried it yet but very excited to do so!

Comment: It actually ended up not working for me, I sort of gave up and I found a template called iOS webview which was $12, and the link is

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/ioswebview-open-specific-links-in-safari-push/4665206?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=john-welt The app template works well. Im sorry though, but I hope my question could help someone else, or this link too!

Comment: the code itself needed some tinkering.. because i did create it on a web page and need some extra config... but 12 dolars for something so trivial feels like a rip off IMHO... but if it did work for you i'm happy.. cheers

Comment: I saw it a long time ago and I thought I should try it myself first then try and ask for help, I didn't think it would be good. I decided to buy it because this forum was my last try. The only thing is it didn't have back and forward buttons, but thanks to your last clipping of code and some looking on the XCode UI, I got it to work exactly the way I needed it to! Thanks1